# Swift Readjust / Resize layout (ASDisplayNode) on show hide of the children node

Tags: ios, swift, asyncdisplaykit

I new to AsyncDisplayKit. So, I create a new app to learn AsyncDisplayKit animationTransition based on my real project code.
The show / hide animation works perfect, but i dont know why the parent node (ASDisplayNode) is not readjusting the layout when the children's hidden (Sorry if my english is bad)

i already tried to put setNeedsLayout() on transitionLayout measurementCompletion, but nothing change

```swift
import AsyncDisplayKit

class HomeView: ASDisplayNode {
    let topWrapperNode: TopWrapperNode
    let loginButtonNode: LoginButtonNode

    override required init() {
        self.topWrapperNode = TopWrapperNode()
        self.loginButtonNode = LoginButtonNode()

        super.init()

        self.automaticallyManagesSubnodes = true
        self.automaticallyRelayoutOnSafeAreaChanges = true
        self.insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea = true
    }

    override func layoutSpecThatFits(_ constrainedSize: ASSizeRange) -> ASLayoutSpec {
        let verticalStackSpec = ASStackLayoutSpec.vertical()

        verticalStackSpec.children = [
            self.topWrapperNode,
            self.loginButtonNode
        ]
        verticalStackSpec.alignItems = .stretch
        verticalStackSpec.justifyContent = .spaceBetween

        let displayInset = ASInsetLayoutSpec(
            insets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 32, bottom: 16, right: 32),
            child: verticalStackSpec
        )

        return ASInsetLayoutSpec(insets: safeAreaInsets, child: displayInset)
    }

    func keyboardShowUpdateLayout(keyboardHeight: CGFloat) {
//        self.topWrapperNode.hideWelcomeLabelNode()
    }

    func keyboardHideUpdateLayout() {
//        self.topWrapperNode.showWelcomeLabelNode()
    }
}

// MARK - TopWrapperNode
class TopWrapperNode: ASDisplayNode {
    let welcomeLabelNode: WelcomeLabelNode
//    let textFieldNode: TextFieldNode

    override required init() {
        welcomeLabelNode = WelcomeLabelNode()
//        textFieldNode = TextFieldNode()

        super.init()

        self.automaticallyManagesSubnodes = true
        self.autoresizesSubviews = true
    }

    override func layoutSpecThatFits(_ constrainedSize: ASSizeRange) -> ASLayoutSpec {
        let verticalStackSpec = ASStackLayoutSpec.vertical()

        verticalStackSpec.children = [
            self.logoImage,
            self.welcomeLabelNode,
//            self.textFieldNode,
        ]
        verticalStackSpec.alignItems = .stretch
        verticalStackSpec.justifyContent = .spaceBetween

        self.backgroundColor = .yellow

        let displayInset = ASInsetLayoutSpec(
            insets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 24, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0),
            child: verticalStackSpec
        )

        return ASInsetLayoutSpec(insets: safeAreaInsets, child: displayInset)
    }

    private let logoImage: ASImageNode = {
        let imageNode = ASImageNode()

        imageNode.image = UIImage(named: "logo")
        imageNode.frame.size = CGSize(
            width: CGFloat(SizeScaler().moderateScale(size: 98)),
            height: CGFloat(SizeScaler().moderateScale(size: 48))
        )
        imageNode.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageNode.style.alignSelf = .center

        return imageNode
    }()

    func hideWelcomeLabelNode() {
        self.welcomeLabelNode.setHide(visibility: true)
        self.welcomeLabelNode.transitionLayout(withAnimation: true, shouldMeasureAsync: false)
    }

    func showWelcomeLabelNode() {
        self.welcomeLabelNode.setHide(visibility: false)
        self.welcomeLabelNode.transitionLayout(withAnimation: true, shouldMeasureAsync: false)
    }
}

// MARK: - WelcomeLabel
class WelcomeLabelNode: ASDisplayNode {
    var isHide: Bool = false

    override required init() {
        super.init()

        self.automaticallyManagesSubnodes = true
        self.autoresizesSubviews = true
        self.shouldAnimateSizeChanges = true
    }

    override func layoutSpecThatFits(_ constrainedSize: ASSizeRange) -> ASLayoutSpec {
        let verticalStackSpec = ASStackLayoutSpec.vertical()

        verticalStackSpec.children = [self.welcomeTitleLabel, self.welcomeDescLabel]
        verticalStackSpec.alignItems = .start

        self.backgroundColor = .green

        return ASInsetLayoutSpec(
            insets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 40, right: 0),
            child: verticalStackSpec
        )
    }

    override func animateLayoutTransition(_ context: ASContextTransitioning) {
        if (self.isHide) {
            let initialTitle = context.initialFrame(for: self.welcomeTitleLabel)
            let initialDesc = context.initialFrame(for: self.welcomeDescLabel)

            self.welcomeTitleLabel.alpha = 1
            self.welcomeTitleLabel.frame = initialTitle
            self.welcomeDescLabel.alpha = 1
            self.welcomeDescLabel.frame = initialDesc

            var finalTitle = context.finalFrame(for: self.welcomeTitleLabel)
            finalTitle.origin.y -= 50
            var finalDesc = context.finalFrame(for: self.welcomeDescLabel)
            finalDesc.origin.y -= 50

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
                self.welcomeTitleLabel.alpha = 0
                self.welcomeTitleLabel.frame = finalTitle
                self.welcomeDescLabel.alpha = 0
                self.welcomeDescLabel.frame = finalDesc
            }, completion: { finished in
                context.completeTransition(finished)
            })
        } else {
            var finalTitle = context.finalFrame(for: self.welcomeTitleLabel)
            finalTitle.origin.y -= 50
            var finalDesc = context.finalFrame(for: self.welcomeDescLabel)
            finalDesc.origin.y -= 50

            self.welcomeTitleLabel.alpha = 0
            self.welcomeTitleLabel.frame = finalTitle
            self.welcomeDescLabel.alpha = 0
            self.welcomeDescLabel.frame = finalDesc

            let initialTitle = context.initialFrame(for: self.welcomeTitleLabel)
            let initialDesc = context.initialFrame(for: self.welcomeDescLabel)

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
                self.welcomeTitleLabel.alpha = 1
                self.welcomeTitleLabel.frame = initialTitle
                self.welcomeDescLabel.alpha = 1
                self.welcomeDescLabel.frame = initialDesc
            }, completion: { finished in
                context.completeTransition(finished)
            })
        }
    }

    let welcomeTitleLabel: QlueWorkLabel = {
        let label = QlueWorkLabel()

        label.setFont34(text: "Selamat datang!", fontType: "medium")
        label.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 32, left: 0, bottom: 8, right: 0)
        label.style.flexGrow = 1
        label.style.flexShrink = 1
        label.backgroundColor = .cyan

        return label
    }()

    let welcomeDescLabel: QlueWorkLabel = {
        let label = QlueWorkLabel()

        label.setFont16or20(
            text: "Pantau pekerjaanmu lebih mudah dengan QlueWork",
            fontType: "regular"
        )
        label.style.flexGrow = 1
        label.style.flexShrink = 1
        label.backgroundColor = .blue

        return label
    }()

    func setHide(visibility: Bool) {
        self.isHide = visibility
    }
}
```

i expect the parent node readjusting layout when the children is hide / show like the flexBox should be.
Can anyone help me or tell me why did i do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after rendering complete, you cannot expect `parentNode` to adjust itself with changing its child dimension

but you can do work arround with ask `parentNode` to re-render itself 
like this

```
DispatchQueue.main.async{
     parentNode.transitionLayout(withAnimation: false,
                            shouldMeasureAsync: true, 
                            measurementCompletion: nil)           
}
```

make sure to run `transitionLayout` on `main thread`

*Happy Texturing*